# Recommended way to implement a Quartz job that holds state

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I need to implement a Quartz job that behaves differently depending on how many times it has been run.

What would you say is the best (or at least a good) way to do that ?

Keeping a counter as state doesn't seem to work since it looks like Quartz recreates it's jobs every time.

Thanks.

Comment: You can then keep the count in a file or a database,though performance degrades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the Quartz [PersistJobDataAfterExecution](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/PersistJobDataAfterExecution.html) annotation allows you to easily implement without using any extra framework / logic.

From PersistJobDataAfterExecution (Quartz 2.2.0) javadoc:

> An annotation that marks a Job class as one that makes updates to its
>   JobDataMap during execution, and wishes the scheduler to re-store the
>   JobDataMap when execution completes.

So when your job starts you simply read your job execution counter from the JobDataMap that is passed to the job's execute method. If the counter is not present in the JobDataMap, you initialize it with 0. At the end of your job execution you increment the counter in the JobDataMap. This updated counter value will then be available during the next job execution.